# pandas resample .csv tick data to OHLC

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .csv file of financial tick data with 3 columns corresponding to date, time  & price. The files has no header.

i.e

01/18/14, 04:09:28, 55.0
01/18/14, 02:18:31, 55.4
01/17/14, 10:42:34, 55.3
01/17/14, 03:18:07, 55.2
...

I want to resample into Daily OHLC using pandas so i can import it into my charting software in the correct format.

I have only gotten so far as opening the file using:

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

Can you help me convert the data in the fomat i have into OHLC with pandas resample.
Thanks

Comment: that's a classic. Group by the date and apply the corresponding function for each OHLC column. In pseudocode:    data.groupby("Date").apply(max) for the H or .apply(min) for the L

Answer (score 3):

If it's still actual there is simplest way to do that in Pandas:

```
data.resample('1D').apply('ohlc')
```

Answer (score 0):

With Python, but without pandas:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import datetime
from decimal import Decimal

class Tick(object):
    pass    

ticks = []
with open('data.csv') as f:
    ticksTemp = []
    lines = [x.strip('\n') for x in f.readlines()]    

    for line in lines:
        columns = [x.strip() for x in line.split(',')]
        if len(columns) != 3:
            continue;
        timeStr = columns[0] + '/' + columns[1]
        time  = datetime.datetime.strptime(timeStr, "%m/%d/%y/%H:%M:%S" )        
        price = columns[2]
        tick = Tick()
        tick.time = time
        tick.price = Decimal(price)
        ticksTemp.append(tick)
    ticks = sorted(ticksTemp, key = lambda x: x.time, reverse=False)


lines = []
first = ticks[0]
last = ticks[-1]
time = first.time
o,h,l,c = first.price, first.price, first.price, first.price
def appendLine():
    lines.append(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')+','+str(o)+ ','+str(h)+','+str(l)+','+str(c))
for tick in ticks:    
    if(tick.time.year != time.year or tick.time.day != time.day):
        appendLine()
        time = tick.time
        o = tick.price
    c = tick.price
    if tick.price > h:
        h = tick.price
    if tick.price < l:
        l = tick.price
if last != first:
    appendLine()
with open('ohlc.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

data.csv:

```
01/18/14, 04:09:28, 55.0
01/18/14, 02:18:31, 55.4
01/17/14, 10:42:34, 55.3
01/17/14, 03:18:07, 55.2
```

ohlc.csv:

```
2014-01-17,55.2,55.3,55.2,55.3
2014-01-18,55.4,55.4,55.0,55.0
```